# Respond to application-wide "hotkey" in Qt

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I've got a simple Qt app, and I just want to respond to the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, regardless of which widget has focus.

Is there some easy signal or something I can hook in to?

I want to use the <kbd>F12</kbd> key to toggle the main window fullscreen on/off.

Comment: Be sure to let the user configure that. There are several other programs that have that exact same feature.

Comment: Falmarri: not sure what you mean. Do you mean to let the user decide which hotkey to use to toggle fullscreen mode? Thx.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I haven't tried, but here is what I would do :

Create a [QShortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html) and make sure its [context](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum) (with `setContext()`) is `Qt::ApplicationShortcut`.

```
shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F12), parent);
shortcut->setContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);
```

Then you just need to connect a slot to the [QShortcut::activated()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html#activated) signal.

Comment: This is one of those things where once you see how to do it, it seems obvious. But before you showed me, I had no clue. ;-)

Comment: It seems to also be easier to use widget wide shortcuts than filtering QKeyEvents

Comment: `parent` must be a pointer to existing widget. One can pass `QApplication::desktop()` as `parent`. It is worth to know that modal windows will block shortcuts even with application context.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the shortcut context to `Qt::ApplicationShortcut` has a serious flaw. It will not work in modal dialogs. So if you want a trully real pan-application-wide shortcut, then you need to override application's `notify()` method. The alternative is to install event filter for the application object but that I suspect would be slower and requires slightly more code. With `notify()` it is very simple:

```
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
    // TODO: constructor etc.

protected:

bool MyApplication::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event) override
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        auto keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_F12 && keyEvent->modifiers() == Qt::NoModifiers)
        {
            // TODO: do what you need to do
            return true;
        }  
    }
    return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "central widget" which all of the other widgets are children of, then you can simply set that as the widget argument for QShortcut.

(Python, qt5)

```
self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("F12"), self.centralwidget, self.goFullScreen)
```

I added this as an answer because the shortcut context flag: `Qt.ApplicationShortcut` did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **HiFile.app** answer but tested working for PySide6 on Python 3.11 (and should be applicable for PySide2 but not tested). You will need to subclass `QApplication` and override the `notify` function.

```py
class Application(QApplication):
    def notify(self, receiver: QObject, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.KeyPress:
            key_event = QKeyEvent(event)
            # Check if key event matches the desire shortcut key
            if key_event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_F12:
                # Do what you want here like toggling fullscreen mode
                return True  # Important! Need to return True for this to work

        return super().notify(receiver, event)
```