# Why QMenu shortcuts didn't triggered from modal QDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt5, shortcut

For this question, i have two windows: one QMainWindow with a QMenu and one QPushButton, and one QDialog window with just a QLabel.

When the user hits the QMenu action, a console message is appeared in the screen.
This action has a shortcut key (F10).

When the user clicks the button one modal QDialog is appeared. I used `show()` method instead of `exec()` or `exec_()` for no stop the mainwindow functionallity. The problem is that from QDialog i cannot trigger the action of QMenu in QMainWindow.

If i re-define the trigger then i should use the shortcut, but how can i resolve it, with no many changes in my code?

**File: untitled.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(363, 62)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 363, 21))
        self.menuMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.actionMenu_action_1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionMenu_action_1)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())

        self.pushButton.setText("Click to open modal Dialog")
        self.menuMenu.setTitle("Menu")
        self.actionMenu_action_1.setText("Menu action 1 (print in console)")
        self.actionMenu_action_1.setShortcut("F10")

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

**File: untitled_2.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(228, 80)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label.setText("Press F10 to test shortcut")

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
```

**File run_app.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
from untitled_2 import Ui_Dialog
import sys
import os

class Run_me:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.open_q_dialog(state))
        
        self.ui.actionMenu_action_1.triggered.connect(lambda:print("Action triggered"))
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def open_q_dialog(self,state):
        self.Dialog = CustomQDialog()
        self.dialog_ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.dialog_ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)
        self.Dialog.show()
        
class CustomQDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwards):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwards)
        self.setModal(True)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Run_me()
```

Maybe the action is not triggered because the QMainWindow is not focused. But it will never be focused because of `self.setModal(True)` in `Custom_QDialog`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @vpoulailleau this example is as minimal as possible.

Comment: I don't think so: for instance the qtdesigner comments, the setwindowtitle and so on are really necessary to spot the issue?

Comment: @vpoulailleau better now?

Comment: yes, it's better.

Comment: See: [Respond to application-wide "hotkey" in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4341492/984421). Even the `Qt.ApplicationShortcut` context won't work in modal dialogs (with neither `QAction` nor `QShortcut`). This seems to be implied in the [QAction docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#details), where it states: "an action must be added to a widget before it can be used; this is also true when the shortcut should be global (i.e., Qt::ApplicationShortcut as Qt::ShortcutContext)".

Answer (score 0):

modification in `run_app.py`:

```py
class CustomQDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self,parent_self,*args,**kwards):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwards)
        self.setModal(True)
        self.addAction(parent_self.ui.actionMenu_action_1)
```

call: `self.Dialog = CustomQDialog(self)`

If there is any other answer feel free to tell me.

Comment: A much simpler solution would be to add the line `self.Dialog.addAction( self.ui.actionMenu_action_1)` in `open_q_dialog`. No other changes are required.

Comment: According they are too many QDialogs, this change would be better to be in constructor.

Comment: It clearly doesn't belong in the constructor, as proved by that ugly `parent_self` argument. If the action is needed in multiple dialogs, it would be better to create a generic dialog-factory method which automatically added the actions.